# Stackoverflow and Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, oauth, openid

If I understand correctly, Facebook Connect uses OAuth and not OpenID. However, on Stackoverflow's login page, there's a short overview about OpenID, which gives an impression that all of the login options implement OpenID. Also, the javascript call to Facebook Connect is `openid.signin('facebook')`, which again gives the impression that FC implements OpenID. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth and OpenID are not mutually exclusive.  [They do two very different things](http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing).

Facebook does, in fact, [implement OpenID](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246/).

Comment: But isn't it that Facebook allows you to log into it using an OpenID, but Facebook Connect actually competes with OpenID as they both offer  an identification service. Facebook Connect is an OpenID-like system, but has nothing to do with OpenID, right?

Comment: @Kate: Sure, but there's no reason they can't do this.  The OpenID implementation is to allow someone to use their Facebook login to authentication against another site (such as StackOverflow).  This simply adds Facebook to a list of places which supply identity, and nothing more.  The Facebook Connect implementation (using OAuth, I suppose) allows developers of other sites/services to deeply integrate with a user's authorization (not just authentication) in their Facebook account data.  StackOverflow doesn't use this, but others certainly can.

Comment: Sure, but unlike Google, Yahoo, and myOpenID, Facebook isn't an OpenID provider. Facebook Connect doesn't comply with the OpenID specification, so strictly speaking SO shouldn't give a wrong impression that Facebook is a provider.

Comment: @Kate: That may be a very valid point.  (I'll admit, I'm no expert on the matter.)  That last bit is starting to sound like a good topic for a Meta question.  (I notice you don't have a Meta account, but are you familiar with it?)

Comment: I'm glad you roughly agree to my point since I only have a very superficial understanding of OpenID etc. Indeed I haven't got a Meta account, but I'll open one and move the discussion there. Thanks.

Comment: @Kate: Don't be put off if it turns out that we're both incorrect and the Meta question gets down-voted into oblivion.  Just remember... Votes and rep shouldn't be taken personally on Stack Overflow.  And they _definitely_ shouldn't be taken personally on Meta Stack Overflow.